# What is the equivalint of Bacon.Bus.plug in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, bacon.js

Is it possible to plug in an `Observable` into a rxjs `Subject`?

In Bacon i can plug in a new stream easily with the `plug` method, but in rxjs I haven't find a one-liner yet. so now I do it like this:

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
var clickStream = new Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
clickStream.subscribe(function(e){
  subject.onNext(e);
});
```

I can't use `merge`, because I render this button later. I would expect a method exists like this:

```
subject.plug(clickStream);
```

Thanks
B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is:

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
var clickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

clickStream.subscribe(subject);
```

You don't need to pass a function that call `subject.onNext` because a `Rx.Subject` is, at same time, an observer and an observable. So, you can subscribe to/from an subject.

Comment: oh, thanks didn't know that [subscribe](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) can work like this, but now reading the docs it's clear